# How to split day and time in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

Database field where day and time is getting stored

[image: Database field where day and time is getting stored]

```html
<div class="col-md-2">Start Time:
  <!-- <span id="day"></span>
  <input type="hidden" name="day" value="{{timeline.day | day: 'h:mm a'}}"> -->
  <br/>{{timeline.day}}
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">End Time<span id="day"></span>
  <input type="hidden" name="day" value="{{timeline.day}}">
  <br/>{{timeline.day}}
</div>
```

I want to split the time and show in the div tag as Start Time: 9:00am and End Time : 10:00am

Comment: If the structure of `day-time1-time2` is consistent, you can just `str.split('-')` and use the last two of the resulting array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just split with '-', and take care of possible `null` values like:

`{{ timeline.day && timeline.day.split("-")[1] }}` for Start time

`{{ timeline.day && timeline.day.split("-")[2] }}` for End time

Here, `timeline.day &&` will assure us we're dealing with not null values.